# Создание символьной ссылки

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть очень важный вопрос к вам. У меня есть две разные бд двух разных сайтов. Пусть это будут bd1 и bd2. В каждой из них одинаковое количество таблиц, они все практически одинаковы, кроме одной в каждой. В bd1 это table1, а в bd2 это table2. Так вот. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы table2 была симлинком (символьной ссылкой) table1.

Я пыталась это сделать с помощью запроса ln -s используя в качестве исходных и целевых файлов как обычные имена этих таблиц, так и их адреса. Я делаю сайт (пока на локальной машине, но операции с бд проводила и у вас) и форум к нему. Все на Джумле.  Форум Kunena является расширением самой Джумлы, а не отдельным движком, как например PhpBB. Я же хочу вынести форум на отдельный поддомен. Я хочу вынести копию сайта на поддомен и объединить некоторые таблицы, типа users и пр, которые должны быть одинаковы для обоих сайтов.

Самый лучший способ присвоения таблице форума данных таблицы с сайта является использование линковки. Занимаюсь этой проблемой уже несколько дней подряд, но при sql запросе к бд все время пишет

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near и дальше текст запроса.`

Нужна помощь профессионалов.

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

[[@Elena](/users/954/elena)](/users/954/elena), кажется, вы немного запутались. То, что вы пытаетесь сделать не делается запросом, это делается утилитами операционной системы из командной строки. Через `phpmyadmin` этого не сделать.

---

Кроме того использовать данные методы не рекомендуется по нескольким причинам, подробнее читайте [здесь](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Symbolic_links_to_databases.html) и [здесь](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Symbolic_links_to_tables.html).

---

Альтернативным способом будет создание реальных таблиц в каждой базе и синхронизация их по крону. Хотя, тоже сомнительный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал жёсткие ссылки? ln без -s =)

Comment: Пробовала, та же ошибка.Может быть я не правильно записываю запрос?НапримерIn test1_users1 test2_users2где test1_users1 находится в одной бд, а test2_users2 находиться в другой.Работаю с phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Каждой таблице соответствует по несколько файлов. Их все надо перелинковать. Найдите директории, хранящие базы данных (что-то типа /var/lib/mysql/база), и все увидите